# Can one easily create an HTML image element from a WebGL texture object?

Tags: webgl

I'd like to take a WebGLTexture object that I've rendered into and use it to create an HTML image element. The goal is to display the result of an offscreen rendering pass for debugging purposes. It should be a lot easier than rendering the texture to a full screen quad, my current debugging method.

Creating a texture from an image element is really easy in WebGL:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "myImg.jpg";

// image loads...

var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(texture);
gl.texImage2D(_gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, _gl.RGBA, _gl.RGBA, _gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

Image loading and decoding is completely taken care of for you.

Is there a similarly easy way to do the reverse? i.e.:

```
// This doesn't work
var img = new Image(texture);

// But maybe this could
var img = createImageFromTexture(texture);

function createImageFromTexture(texture) {
    // ... some combination of tricks ...
}
```

If there is a way to do this, I'm sure it will be useful in contexts outside of debugging. I'll continue to see if I can find a way to do it, but I feel like someone has had to have attempted this before.

Comment: I saw this when searching for a way:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702032/accessing-image-texture-data-texels-on-webgl

Comment: Did you ever find a way?

Answer (score 26):

You can create a [framebuffer](http://www.javascripture.com/WebGLFramebuffer) backed by a texture and then read the raw pixel data out of the framebuffer using [gl.readPixels()](http://www.javascripture.com/WebGLRenderingContext#readPixels).  Once you have the data pixel, you can copy them to a 2D canvas using [ImageData](http://www.javascripture.com/ImageData).  Then you can construct an Image by setting the image's src property to [canvas.toDataURL()](http://www.javascripture.com/HTMLCanvasElement#toDataURL).

```
function createImageFromTexture(gl, texture, width, height) {
    // Create a framebuffer backed by the texture
    var framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

    // Read the contents of the framebuffer
    var data = new Uint8Array(width * height * 4);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    gl.deleteFramebuffer(framebuffer);

    // Create a 2D canvas to store the result 
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Copy the pixels to a 2D canvas
    var imageData = context.createImageData(width, height);
    imageData.data.set(data);
    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    return img;
}
```

Comment: While this does work, it seems like an awfully inefficient solution. Is there a better API for this?

Comment: Where are you using the result from this?  Would the canvas work instead of making an img out of it? Another option to look into would be to use ImageData and createImageBitmap to create an ImageBitmap instead of an img.

Comment: I want to display webgl shader heavy rendered content in a React DOM <img> element. The content is generated on the fly but is static otherwise. I'm using a single WebGL context to generate a bunch of previews for different settings. And the buttons show the preview.

Comment: Starting out from your recommendation I actually found `canvas.toBlob` then using `URL.createObjectURL` should significantly improve performance. Will test and maybe post an answer if it's good.

Comment: Yeah, `toBlob` will be an improvement on the browsers that support it. It will allow the main thread to process other tasks while encoding the image. It still needs an image encode and an allocation to hold the encoded image though. If you can change the `img`s to `canvas`es and `putImageData` the image data into the canvas, that would probably be the biggest improvement.

Comment: [ImageBitmapRenderingContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmapRenderingContext)
This could be an even better solution, but I didn't end up pursuing more performance yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of running a node.js server in conjunction with toDataURL() to transmit multiple images directly to disk:

http://www.oampo.co.uk/2011/01/exporting-video-from-webgl/

Answer (score 0):

A WebGL context is a canvas, and there are several well documented ways to get an image out of a canvas, so the basic methodology is going to look something like this:

1. Draw your texture on a fullscreen (well, full-canvas) quad. It will
   be best if you resize the canvas before hand so the canvas has a
   1-to-1 pixel ratio with the texture image you are trying to draw.
2. Use a method like the [one described here](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) to get the image data
   out of the canvas.

If you just want to actually save the image you'll probably have to send it to a server to be processed, but if you're looking to simply display the image on the same page that it was rendered you can set the dataURI that you were given to the `img` tag's `src` attribute and it should display properly.

Comment: I'm struggling to use the method from step 2. to actually get an image from a WebGL canvas. All I'm getting at the moment is a completely translucent .png image. Is there something I need to set up in my Canvas that I'm missing?