# Copy texture from GPU to CPU

Tags: javascript, html, gpu, webgl, textures

How can I copy a texture from GPU memory to the CPU in WebGL? I am updating the texture using texSubImage2D in runtime.

I would like to avoid:

- storing a copy of a texture on a canvas
- rendering to texture and call readPixels

Is there any other way?

Already read these (which are useful for textures that are not updated during execution):

- [Accessing image/texture data (texels) on WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702032/accessing-image-texture-data-texels-on-webgl)
- [Can one easily create an HTML image element from a WebGL texture object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191083/can-one-easily-create-an-html-image-element-from-a-webgl-texture-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no other way than to attach your texture to an FBO and perform a readPixels.

Answer (score 1):

readPixels or (since readPixels tends to be a bit slow) you could render it on a quad of the size of your canvas.

With

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

that texture would be in the img variable. For that to work you need to init you
gl with something like this

```
gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
```