# Read pixels from a WebGL texture

Tags: textures, webgl

I have a WebGLTexture object. How do I get pixels of that texture (similar to WebGL's readPixels, but for a texture)?

One idea I have is to create a canvas and a WebGL context with preserveDrawingBuffer=true, and render my texture on this canvas so that it shows 2D flat, and then use readPixels. Is this approach reasonable? Does anyone have a sample code for this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try attaching the texture to a framebuffer and then calling readPixels on the frame buffer.

*at init time*

```
// make a framebuffer
fb = gl.createFramebuffer();

// make this the current frame buffer
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

// attach the texture to the framebuffer.
gl.framebufferTexture2D(
    gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

// check if you can read from this type of texture.
let canRead = (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) == gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);

// Unbind the framebuffer
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
```

*at read time*

```
if (canRead) {
   // bind the framebuffer
   gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

   // read the pixels
   gl.readPixels(......);

   // Unbind the framebuffer
   gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
}
```

For textures of format = gl.RGBA, type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE canRead should always be true. For other formats and types canRead might be false.

Comment: So, as I understand, this will work only for textures of level=0, as gl.framebufferTexture2D requires level=0. Is there a way to handle non-zero levels as well?

Comment: You could render a specific level using texture2DLod in your shaders into another texture's level 0 then read that.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for textures that are not unsigned bytes.

Comment: @matth It seems to work for floating-point-channel textures on my computer, with the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Hi @gman Is there a way to read from a framebuffer attached to an texture array? I tried with a render to multiple target sample, turns out `readpixels` can only read data from the first layer. (Tested on chrome 58 win10)

Comment: Seeing as the tag is "webgl" I imagine this is JS, and `bool canRead` should be either `var canRead` or `let canRead`, but not `bool`. ;)

Comment: Also, `checkFramebufferStatus()` requires the parameter `gl.FRAMEBUFFER`. ;)