# How can I inspect or dump texture contents in WebGL?

Tags: webgl

I'm trying to implement a calculation using floating point textures in WebGL that involves multiples steps, switching the output texture in between each one. Not entirely unexpected, my initial implementation results in a simply black screen.

Is there a way to dump the contents of a texture in WebGL, or inspect it in any other way? This would be very useful in this case to step through the calculation and check if the contents of the textures are correct.

I tried some of the WebGL debugging tools that I found, but they either didn't have this ability, or don't exist anymore like the Chrome Canvas Inspector. I know I could do this the hard way, rewriting my code to stop at different steps, rendering the output to colors, saving the result to an image and then extracting the values again, but I was hoping that there is an easier and more convenient way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read pixels from a WebGL texture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626606/read-pixels-from-a-webgl-texture)

Answer (score 0):

To read one of your subresults, you may try:
`readPixels` https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.12

or `texImage2D` which is overloaded and part of larger "texture object interface". One signature behaves almost identical to `readPixels`
https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.8

Data can be then readed from javascript as binary data. But I guess this is the hard way you are not looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[spector.js](https://spector.babylonjs.com) provides such feature, but only for textures passed to shaders. Use these steps to view your texture:

1. Enable spector.js by pressing its red icon in a button in your toolbar.
2. The icon will turn green, press on it again.
3. In the opened dialog window, press on a red button to capture drawing commands. This assumes your WebGL canvas is in a state suitable for capturing.
4. Wait a few seconds (spector.js documentation says that processing capture data may even take minutes when you have a large number of drawing commands.
5. Select a drawing command that uses your texture. Textures have IDs in spector.js, you may need to see what id is assigned to your texture with the JavaScript debugger before searching for a texture in spector.js capture summary.