# Three.js marker on mesh

Tags: three.js

I'm working on a visualization that uses a height map to create a 3d terrain, and want to add some markers for locations of cities on the map. I'm guessing some sort of `raycaster` and `intersectObject` might do it, but I'm lost as to how to place a marker directly on the surface of the terrain. For instance, I know that a city is at (640, 480) in the pixel units of my texture, so I'm doing something like:

```
// This is the terrain, loaded from a PNG of the digital elevation model
var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( bumpTexture.image.width, bumpTexture.image.height, 600, 450 );
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeo, customMaterial );
plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
plane.position.y = 0;
scene.add( plane );

// At (640, 480) of the image, there should be a marker directly on top of the mesh. 
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 20, 20, 20 ), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
cube.position.x = 640;
cube.position.y = 0;
cube.position.z = 480;
scene.add(cube);
raycaster.setFromCamera(cube, camera );
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(plane);
console.log(raycaster, intersects);
// no intersects???
```

Any suggestions, Threejs wizards?

Comment: Raycaster uses unmodyfied geometry (the one you have before vertex displacement) so it wouldn't work good there probably. If you know texture location of city - could you just read height value on CPU and use it for setting marker height? With [`gl.readPixels()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/readPixels) for example ([related link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626606/read-pixels-from-a-webgl-texture)).

Comment: Interesting, I'll take a gander