# Process THREE.Texture in webworkers

Tags: three.js, webgl

I would like to process THREE.Texture in web workers to help post processing effects such as bloom. For instance for the bloom effect, I would first draw the scene on a THREE.Texture object and then I would like to handle the blur process in the web worker. What would be the **most efficient** way to pass the THREE.Texture data to the worker and create a new THREE.Texture from the data obtained from the worker. Since I would do that 60 times per second ideally, I need a fast and memory friendly way to do that (memory friendly: not to create new objects in a loop but rather re-use existing objects).

I'm aware that canvas2DContext.getImageData may be helpful but that probably is not the best way since I'd draw to canvas 60 times per second and that would slow things down.

Thanks!

PS: I should specify that in this approach, I don't intend to wait for the worker to finish processing the texture to render the final result. Since most of the objects are static I don't think that would be a big deal anyway. I wanna test it to see how it goes for the dynamic objects though.

Comment: Why don't you stick to the three.js examples and use for example `UnrealBloomPass`? It's using the GPU for very efficient processing. I don't think, you will get anything close in terms of performance when you will use webworkers. Your approach sounds very odd to me. https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom

Comment: I know but I want to go experimental. My idea is to handle the blur inside the workers and have one less WebGL render call (the blur pass).

Comment: You can use `canvas.getImageData()` to retrieve an `Uint8ClampedArray` that represents your raw image data. You can then send the respective `ArrayBuffer` to a worker via [Transferable Objects](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/12/Transferable-Objects-Lightning-Fast). If you are going to use multiple workers, you have to split up the original `Uint8ClampedArray` into multiple array buffers since transferable objects are only valid in a single execution context. In any event, your performance will be worse than using the GPU. So I'm not sure it makes sense to invest time in this.

Comment: Well I know that getImageData is really slow so in my question I asked for a way other than getImageData, if that's possible.

Comment: Using `WebGLRenderingContext.readPixels()` like in the following example should work, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626606/read-pixels-from-a-webgl-texture

Comment: You will not be able to do this 60 times a second. "Interactive" is a relative term, and you might not have it any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing a GPU based texture to a web worker would not speed up anything in fact it would be significantly slower.

It's extremely slow to transfer memory from the GPU to the CPU (and CPU to GPU as well) relative to doing everything on the GPU. The only way to pass the contents of a texture to a worker is to ask WebGL to copy from the GPU to the CPU (using `gl.readPixels` on in three whatever it's wrapper for `gl.readPixels` is) and then transfer the result to the worker. Then in the worker all you could do is a slow CPU based blur (slower than it would have been on the GPU), then you'd have to transfer it back to the main thread only to upload it again via `gl.texImage2D` or telling three.js to do it for you which is also a slow operation copying the data from the CPU back to the GPU.

The fast way to apply a blur is to do it on the GPU.

Further, there is no way to share WebGL resources between the main thread and a worker nor is there likely to be anytime soon. Even if you could share the resource and then from the worker ask the GPU to do the blur that would save no time as well as for the most part GPUs don't run different operations in parallel (not generically multi-process like CPUs) so all you'd end up doing is asking the GPU to do the same amount of work.

Comment: Yes I know it is supposed to be slower but the reason I want to try something like this is that the GPU based bloom effect first renders the scene as the texture, then passes this texture to the blur shader and then combines the result and the current scene in another shader. It seems to me that it is already an expensive opeartion and loads of gl.textImage2D and WebGL draw calls are made anyway. Since the workers do not block the main thread besides passing the data and receiving it back, I thought I should give workers a try.

Comment: There should be no call to `gl.texImage2D` after the initial setup. If you're seeing that there's a bug in your code or it's being used for something unrelated (uploading a video for example)

Comment: Yes, my bad. I wanted to say that the reason I want to try something like this is to try to reduce the amount of WebGL draw calls for the bloom effect. I also added a little PS to my question.

Comment: This really is not the route you should be taking and this answer should be accepted.