# Dynamically loaded Image drawn to a canvas in javascript has incorrect (but close) RGB values

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, nginx

I have some `.PNG` images hosted on my own NGINX webserver and I've found that when I load them programatically and then draw them to a canvas via `context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);` and pull the image data via `context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data` that the pixel `RGB` values are incorrect.  I did find that if I open the image in its own tab and drag it to my desktop it saves as a `.BMP` with the incorrect color values, yet if I 'file save as...' it saves correctly as a `.PNG` with correct color.  so I'm not 100% certain this is a js issue or a server issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaFP2.png
Top is what I expect
Bottom is what I get

Comment: You're not giving us much to work with here. No code, no file, no config, no expected and returned values...

Comment: There is no code to post because its a simple image load, draw to canvas, and pull image data based on what I typed above.

Comment: Looks like it might be a browser rendering issue.  What happens in another browsers?

Comment: Happens across IE, Chrome, and Nightly. As an example, the first pixel, a pixel of rgb(8,8,8), loads as rgb(13,13,13)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To speed up canvas browsers will alpha-premultiply the color values in its buffer.

This is a lossy process so when you do `.getImageData` the result will often be "close to but not exactly" what you originally drew on the canvas.

Comment: Is there a function available that will give me the true value?

Comment: @Billy, No, not with html canvas. :-(

Comment: Do you have a link or source where I can read more about these kinds of subtleties in html5? Seems interesting.

Comment: The WhatWG is the source of the way html5 canvas "should" be implemented by all browsers:  http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element.  And if you "lurk" on the "issues" boards of each browser  you can see where the browser falls short of the way things "should" be implemented.  Cheers!